# How can i setupt XenCenter to find virtual cdrom drives?

Tags: xenserver, citrix

I am making an attempt to assist a consumer however i'm slightly out of my depth, they need a XS6 dedicated server, and that i have created a series of virtual drives for numerous distros, mistreatment isos we've got. as an example /mnt/centos6.2 - I conjointly tried /media/centos6.2 - but once I conceive to install VMs through XenCenter, the server videodisk drives section is blank. however would I mount a drive so XenCenter detects it properly as a drive?

[edit:] found this:http://www.interfaceplanet.com/citrix-web-interface.aspx which got the isos available and there, but the test vm I tried to create using a centos 6.2 iso gave me the error:

24/01/2014 8:19:13 AM Error: Starting VM 'Test' - INVALID_SOURCE - Unable to access a required file in the specified repository: file:///tmp/cdrom-repo-WPN1yR/isolinux/vmlinuz.

Answer (score 0):

It appears like they're doing weird stuff. place all the isos in a directory on windows and share it on the network ( samba beneath UNIX works nice too). Then from the XenCenter user interface add a replacement storage repository. opt for "windows file sharing" iso library. currently you may be ready to mount these isos and install vms